# Copy changed files from CVS repository

Tags: git, debian, cvs

I'm trying to move my CVS repo to git. I've imported all the CVS history to git, but I just need to move across all the changed/new files. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm using debian linux, so would prefer command line tools.

Comment: Are you saying you did `git-cvsimport` and after changes were added to the original cvs repository? You could just redo the import process...

Comment: The files that have changed are in a dev directory and they're not ready to be checked in yet. I'm exploring some other options to get the changed files into a new directory.

Comment: You could create a dev branch and rerun the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to grab the changed files and copy them into another directory:

```
cvs -qn update -d 2>/dev/null | grep '^[M|\?|P] ' | awk '{print $2}' > files.list
while read file; do cp -r -f --parents "$file" /tmp/dest/; done < files.list
```

Basically, cvs -qn update -d does a mock update (doesn't change files), piped to grep to only list the changed files, use awk to exclude the M, P, ? etc, output to a file.

Loop over the lines in the new file using the cp --parents to preserve directory structure

Answer (score 0):

One approach, described in "[HOW-TO import and export to and from Git and CVS](http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/HOW-TO_import_and_export_to_and_from_Git_and_CVS)" is to use patch sets from CVS in order for you to update regularly your git repo for any new changes from your CVS repo:

Initial import:

> make sure you have a `$CVSROOT` parameter initialized in your session, and run the following command:

```
$ git cvsimport -d $CVSROOT -C dir_to_create -r cvs -k cvs_module_to_checkout
```

Long version:

```
cvsps -x --norc -u -A ojs2 > ~/cvsps.out
mkdir ojs
cd ojs
# the ojs2 at the end is the CVS module name
git-cvsimport -o HEAD -v -k -P ~/cvsps.out ojs2
```

Then:

```
$ git config cvsimport.module cvs_module_to_checkout
$ git config cvsimport.r cvs
$ git config cvsimport.d $CVSROOT
```

> Once you run those config commands, keeping the `master` branch up-to-date can simply be done by:

```
$ git cvsimport -k
```